# Sourcing a prajñāpāramitā statement

Tags: prajnaparamita, mulamadhyamakakarika

In the Madhyamakaśāstra, Venerable Vimalākṣa quotes the Pañcaviṃśatisāhasrikāprajñāpāramitāsūtra:

菩薩有我亦非行無我亦非行
"If the bodhisatva has a self, he cannot act. With no self too, he cannot act."
T1564.24b29

I've read this before, but finding it in the sūtra is proving daunting. Where in the root sūtra can we find the passage the Venerable is quoting? Also, where can we find the corresponding section of the Mahāprajñāpāramitāśāstra commentary concerning this statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching CBETA shows that this passage, as given, is not cited from any known Chinese Prajñāpāramitā translation.

We find the following in T 235 (Kumārajīva's Vajracchedikā translation)

須菩提！若菩薩有我相、人相、眾生相、壽者相，即非菩薩。(T 235; 8.235a10-11：

This passage in T 220 (Xuanzang) seems more promising as the source.

不作是念：『我亦行亦不行般若波羅蜜多。』(T 220; 5.33c20-21).

Answer (score 2):

The "root" is a passage from the 18th chapter of the MMK:

> 諸佛或說我 或說於無我 諸法實相中 無我無非我 諸法實相者 心行言語斷 無生亦無滅 寂滅如涅槃 一切實非實 亦實亦非實 非實非非實
> 是名諸佛法
>
> All Buddhas either speak of self or speak of no self. All dharmas’
> true aspect, within this, there is neither self nor no self. All
> dharmas’ true aspect is defined as mental activity’s and spoken
> language’s ending.There is no arising and no cessation, there is calm
> extinction, such is nirvāṇa. All is real, all is unreal, all is both
> real and unreal, all is neither real nor unreal: this is called all
> Buddhas’ dharma.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The root of the quotation is from the Pañcaviṃśatisāhasrikāprajñāpāramitāsūtra. It is not originally from the MMK. Also, this quotation you gave is not from the same area of the 18th chapter of the MMK commentary. I will give you brownie points though since you used my translation.

Comment: If you want a more updated version, I'm now translating the passage like this:

"All of the Buddhas speak concerning the self
or speak concerning selflessness,
but within the true aspect of all phemonena
there is neither the self nor selflessness.

The true aspect of all phenomena
is the ending of the mind activity and spoken language.
Unarisen and unending,
it is quiet tranquility. It is nirvana.

All is real. All is unreal.
All is real and unreal.
All is neither real nor unreal.
This is called the Dharma of all Buddhas."

Comment: Easier to read for English speakers, less plural genitives (i.e. "all dharmas' true aspect") In the above, change "the mind activity" to "mental activity."

Comment: Wouldn't a better way to say it be, "the true nature of all phenomena is *beyond* mental activity and spoken language"? (instead of "ending of").